# How to fix error report upon boot-up and after sleep mode, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, crash, reboot

I am using Ubuntu Version LTS 18.04. I have the following error every time I reboot the computer:

`_usr_bin_gnome-shell.125.crash  _usr_bin_Xwayland.125.crash`

**EDITS:**

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions:

```
"no such file or directory"
```

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 23 22:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb 23 21:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 23 22:02 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 23 22:02 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

ls -al /var/crash:

```
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Mar 24 09:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Apr 29  2018 ..
```

Comment: Probably a bad GNOME Shell extension. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /var/crash`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Hello @heynnema, I posted a few edits which Ihope will clarify error report issue.

Comment: Thank you David, not sure what you did but the "edits" format above is much cleaner.

Comment: It looks like the 2nd and 3rd outputs are incomplete, or incorrect. Can you try again for me? Thanks!

Comment: When you get an error message on your screen, are you clicking on `Send Report`, `Don't Send Report`, or just closing the window by clicking on the `x`?

Comment: @heynnema, Those are complete outputs, minus a link to Conical website.  I most often click the "send report" , then go in and "rm" the error reports.  This sometimes, seems to repress the error pop up

Comment: The `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /var/crash` command outputs are missing the actual filenames in those directories. Please try again. Also, no need to manually `rm` those files, as the system will take care of them on its own.

Comment: @heyyema - Edits 2 above is verbatim

Comment: That output looks better. See my initial answer. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema  Implemented answer. No error report since. Thanks.

Comment: Good news, so far! Now two things... if it does crash, don't send reports, and **don't** manually delete files out of /var/crash... and two... if it does seem to fix your problem, please do remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema  Will do, thanks again.  I will give it another day or two, but still no error report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Wayland crashes, try this...

In the `terminal` app, edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`...

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Find this:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Change it to this:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`

```
reboot
```